# Cannot save a new ADF (not extend) after trying to relocalize to another ADF

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-project-tango

Just for a little context, what I'am trying to do is:

1.Load most recent ADF file to relocalize

2.If after a certain time the relocalized wasn't posible ask to choose an ADF file or create a new one

3.Create a new ADF file

4.Save file.

When trying to save, I a get an error "Could not save area description". While debugging I noticed that I don't get TANGO_COORDINATE_FRAME_AREA_DESCRIPTION while recording the new ADF file

If the first step is skipped then saving a new ADF is possible.

Is there a restriction or something I'm missing when calling Startup(someAreaDescription) and then calling Startup(null), I have tried tangoApp.Shutdown() but nothing changes?

Answer (score 0):

I am not a expert on Unity, Just explain general concept on Tango ADF.

The Workflow for "Load ADF + Learning on":

you need to Re-localized the ADF areas which is the area ADF loaded.

without the pre-condition, you never can save the new ADFs on this mode.
But you can disconnect Tango(should have the same scripts in Unity),
Connect with ADF learning on only. start learning.
it should works.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't explain myself very well, english is not my first language. I'm not trying to (Load ADF + Learning On), what I'm trying to do is: Load the last ADF created and relocalize to it. If after a certain time the relocalization wasn't possible I ask the user to choose a ADF file from the list of files previously created or to create a brand new ADF file. And here is where I find the issue of not being able to save a new ADF file after trying and failing to relocalize to an existing one. I have also tried to disconnect, and it does disconnect but still my issue is not fixed.